# MYSQL DELETE rows in query with substr

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, substr

I would like to remove rows table1.name from table where table1.name starts with 'product-'

```
mysql_request("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE substr(name, 0, 8) = 'product-'");
```

It's very ridiculous but this query doesn't work at all. Any ideas how to make it?

Comment: Is MySQL set in safe-mode? Also, why not try `\`name\` LIKE 'product-%'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the key is start with 'product'. Try:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE name like 'product-%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Hm - Looks good. Should work (provided you switched to the correct database). Do you have an error message?
Another possible approach would be:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE name like 'product-%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE name like 'product-%';
```

or this (regular expressions syntax):

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE name REGEXP '^product-';
```